# how to call array 2D in PHP?

Tags: forms

I have array 2d below, the variable ($C00 etc) has value itself.

```
   $matriks = array(array($C00, $C01, $C02, $C03),
             array($C10, $C11, $C12, $C13),
             array($C20, $C21, $C22, $C23),
             array($C30, $C31, $C32, $C33));
```

i want to use that array 2d on next page, with submit form method POST:
i dunno this code corret or not :).

```
foreach ($matriks as $val) {
foreach ($val as $v) {
echo '<input type="hidden" name="Matriks[][]" value="'.$v.'">';
}}
```

then how to call it in action page? (after submit)
my code like this but still eror.

```
$matriks=array();
foreach($_POST['Matriks'] as $key => $val) {
foreach ($val as $k => $v) {
    $matriks[$key][$k] = $v;
}}
```

Comment: Could you kindly describe a bit more clearly..?

Answer (score 0):

Update this part of your code as shown:

```
foreach ($matriks as $i => $val) {
    foreach ($val as $v) {
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="Matriks[' . $i . '][]" value="'.$v.'">' . "\n";
    }
}
```

Using the `$i` key ensures that your matrix is well represented in the DOM, else all your values would only overwrite each-other at position `[0, 0]`.

If you `var_dump` your `$_POST` on the action page, you'd see your matrix output like this:

```
array (size=1)
  'Matriks' => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => 
        array (size=4)
          0 => string '00' (length=2)
          1 => string '01' (length=2)
          2 => string '02' (length=2)
          3 => string '03' (length=2)
      1 => 
        array (size=4)
          0 => string '10' (length=2)
          1 => string '11' (length=2)
          2 => string '12' (length=2)
          3 => string '13' (length=2)
      2 => 
        array (size=4)
          0 => string '20' (length=2)
          1 => string '21' (length=2)
          2 => string '22' (length=2)
          3 => string '23' (length=2)
      3 => 
        array (size=4)
          0 => string '30' (length=2)
          1 => string '31' (length=2)
          2 => string '32' (length=2)
          3 => string '33' (length=2)
```